# Cannot mount NodeMCU with MicroPython on Mac OS X

Tags: python, nodemcu

I've recently bought a NodeMCU board and flashed MicroPython in it. I've read about the `boot.py` and `main.py` scripts, but I can't understand how to access them...

I have succesfully connected to the Python REPL with the screen command and everything works fine. Is there a way to mount it as an external drive on Mac OS X? Because I haven't found a way till now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is not an arduino question, it's a micropython question.

Answer (score 2):

The typical NodeMCU board uses a fixed function CP-210x USB-Serial chip.  This cannot appear to a host operating system as any ordinary sort of storage device, so it is not "mountable" via conventional storage drivers.

Access would need to be through some client program - or else, at a bit of a stretch, some highly specialized driver that created something fitting the host operating system's idea of filesystem, but proxying the actions through operatings the CP-210x and software running in the ESP8266 can support.

Answer (score 1):

You have a NodeMCU; not a pyboard. I'm not sure that the USB Drive option is available in the NodeMCU.

I flashed microPython in a NodeMCU and Linux doesn't recognize it as a external drive or any other media type, but REPL thru serial monitor works fine.

Comment: meanwhile I've discovered ampy, which does what I need!

Comment: Adafruit MicroPython Tool (ampy) - Utility to interact with a MicroPython board over a serial connection. Ampy is meant to be a simple command line tool to manipulate files and run code on a MicroPython board over its serial connection. With ampy you can send files from your computer to a MicroPython board's file system, download files from a board to your computer, and even send a Python script to a board to be executed.